# SettingWithCopyWarning won't go away regardless of the approach

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Let me start by saying that I understand what the warning is, why it's there and I've read a ton of questions which have been answered. Using today's `pandas` (1.2.3) and `scikit-learn` (0.24.1) this warning simply won't go away:

I have a dataframe loaded from a pickle, nothing too complex:

```
print(df)

    Date  Sales     Labels
0   2013-01-01      0 5024.00000
1   2013-01-02   5024 5215.00000
2   2013-01-03   5215 5552.00000
3   2013-01-04   5552 5230.00000
4   2013-01-05   5230    0.00000
..         ...    ...        ...
747 2015-01-18      0 5018.00000
748 2015-01-19   5018 4339.00000
749 2015-01-20   4339 4786.00000
750 2015-01-21   4786 4606.00000
751 2015-01-22   4606 4944.00000
```

I'm using the *accepted* answer of how to min-max the columns `Sales` and `Labels` because I want to preserve order and keep the `Dates`:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df[['Sales', 'Labels']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Sales', 'Labels']])
```

This gives me the following warning (as you can guess):

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I've tried:

```
df.loc[:, 'Sales'] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Sales']])
```

And I still get the warning (even though now it won't tell me which line it is coming from!).

Which makes me wonder if `scikit-learn` is internally calling it in the old-fashioned way, and that's where the warning is now coming from.

I've also tried using a `.copy()` which I understand is only masking the issue, but the warning is still present.

Is there another way to apply `MinMaxScaler` without the warning?

Comment: What accepted answer you refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `df` is a subset of another dataframe, for example:

```
rawdata = pd.DataFrame({'Date':range(5),
'Sales':np.random.uniform(1000,2000,5),
'Labels':np.random.uniform(1000,2000,5),
'Var':np.random.uniform(0,1,5)})
```

And you subset `df` from this, but bear in mind this is a slice of the original dataframe `rawdata`. Hence if we try to scale, it throws a warning:

```
df = rawdata[['Date','Sales','Labels']]
df[['Sales', 'Labels']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Sales', 'Labels']])

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

If you scale and transform the original dataframe, it works:

```
rawdata[['Sales','Labels']] = scaler.fit_transform(rawdata[['Sales', 'Labels']])
```

You have to think about whether you need the original data frame, you can do this, just that it cost more memory:

```
df = rawdata[['Date','Sales','Labels']].copy()
df[['Sales', 'Labels']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Sales', 'Labels']])
```

Comment: So the warning follows all the way up to the original data split?! That does make sense, I'll follow the code.

Comment: That was it! Well done, you debugged this without even having seen the code :-D

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this warning coming up is unordered indices. For example, if you split a dataset into subsets (i.e., train and test splits common in ML), then the indices are not in order.

A quick fix is to reset the indices of the subset df if they won't matter in a downstream task.

```
df = df.reset_index()
```